# Angular PrimeNg: p-table not detected using @ViewChild

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng

This is my related code:

```
import { DataTable } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'search.component.html'
})
export class SearchComponent {
    @ViewChild(DataTable)
    private dataTable: DataTable;

    ngAfterViewInit () {
        if (this.dataTable) {
            console.log("detected");
        }
        else {
            console.log("not detected");
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to pick up my `p-table` component.

Any ideas about the reason `p-table` is not detected?

Obviously, `p-table` directive is present on template.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using `p-table` this should be

```
   @ViewChild(Table) private dataTable: Table;
```

`Table` instead of `DataTable`

Comment: Note that if a table is not static (isn't present at any time and exists only under some known circumstances), you should mention it in your ViewChild decorator (or you'll have your ```dataTable``` empty), like this: ```@ViewChild(Table, { static: false }) private dataTable: Table;```